# Can't connect to Azure Cache for Redis using SSL

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to connect to an Azure Cache For Redis resource from an asp.net MVC application using StackExchange.Redis and it only works if I set the port to 6379 and ssl=false in the connection string.

```
public class RedisCacheHelper
{
    static RedisCacheHelper()
    {
        lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(****.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=******=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False);
        });
    }

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to connect using ssl=true and the ssl port I get:

> "No connection is active/available to service this operation: GET
> ******; A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName:
> DESKTOP-EMHQA7J, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=12,Max=8191), v: 2.2.4.27433"}

This docs say I should have a .key or .pfx file but I don't see where I can get such file from Azure.
https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_csharp/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.pfx` or `.key` file.

You can [download my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/azure-cache-redis_encryptdecrypt), and it works for me.

[image]

In local,

[image]

After deployed,

[image]

For more details, pls check below post. The sample code is same as you.

[Encrypting and decrypting values in Azure redis cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882678/encrypting-and-decrypting-values-in-azure-redis-cache/63896400#63896400)