# cant connecto to aws redis from stackexchange.redis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

my code sample to connect is like:

```
 this._connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { { "redisleaderboard-001.fcwfbh.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com", 6379 },
                {"redisleaderboard-002.fcwfbh.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379",6379 } ,
                {"redisleaderboard-003.fcwfbh.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379",6379 } },
            User = "AKIAUVZ3ROZPXZITMV4W",
            Password = "2J4eEz11awbjZDTU6s14xbacvycEsx0t1L4jYryi",
            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            Ssl = true,
            SyncTimeout =5000,
            
           
        });
        _database = this._connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
```

but i cant connect to the aws server with this config. what is the right settings for it?

Comment: Might want to reset your credentials now that you've leaked them to the public internet. This is also a good excuse to not hard code credentials in your code and use a configuration file.

Comment: @gunr2171 they are changed. dont worry about it.

Comment: [Does the sample code useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63896400/7687666) And if you want add mulitiple instance, you can refer [the official doc](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html#basic-configuration-strings). By the way, pls check for restrictions like firewalls in AWS portal.